# how to use sharedModule in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-modules, ng-modules

I have one angular2 component which I want to share among multiple modules.

So I wrote below sharedModule ,

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {GenericComponent} from './generic/generic.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ GenericComponent ],
  exports:      [ GenericComponent ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

then I added this sharedModule to multiple modules as below:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I also added sharedModule to generic.module.ts similarly ,

**generic.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ //.. here I have added all the components that generic uses ]
})
export class GenericModule { }
```

but I am getting below error when I am trying to use generic component inside components of generic.module.ts

> Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'GenericModule'

Comment: I don't see that `GenericModule` anywhere.. pls add it.

Comment: Are you also importing GenericModule into SharedModule? Ive had this happen before where it caused a failing circular dependency

Comment: @peeskillet no.. i am importing generic.component inside sharedModule,and I am importing this shared module inside genericModule & AppModule

Comment: @peeskillet Actually I have this problem. My sharedModule contains a pipe and a module (A), the module A need the pipe of ShareModule, so I import it from within the module A. But I have a error `Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'A'`. What I'm suppose to do in this case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code from my app using a shared module:

App module:

```
import { AboutModule } from './about/about.module';
import { SharedModule }   from './shared/shared.module';
import { Menubar, MenuItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), SharedModule.forRoot(), 
               HomeModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ appRoutingProviders ]

}) 

export class AppModule {}
```

The home module:

```
import { SharedModule }   from '../shared/shared.module';
import {routing} from './home.routing'


@NgModule({
    imports: [ SharedModule, routing],
    declarations: [ HomeComponent, LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, VerifyComponent, 
                   VerifyEmailComponent, ForgotComponent, ForgotVerifyComponent, 
                   ChangeComponent, ChallengeComponent, LogoutComponent ], 
    bootstrap: [ HomeComponent ],
    providers: [ ]

}) 

export class HomeModule {}
```

And the shared module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, MenubarModule, GalleriaModule, InputTextModule, PanelModule, ButtonModule,
            DropdownModule, DialogModule, AccordionModule, CalendarModule, SelectButtonModule, CheckboxModule,
            ProgressBarModule, DataTableModule],
  declarations: [ ErrorMessagesComponent, FoodDashboardComponent ],
  exports: [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule,
            MenubarModule, GalleriaModule, InputTextModule, PanelModule, ButtonModule, DropdownModule, DialogModule, AccordionModule, CalendarModule,
            SelectButtonModule, CheckboxModule, DataTableModule, ProgressBarModule, ErrorMessagesComponent, FoodDashboardComponent ]
})

export class SharedModule {
  //
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [SettingsService, AppMenuService, AuthorizationService, LoginService, RegisterService, ThemeService, ValidationService,
        NutritionixService, AuthGuardService, CalculationService, ChallengeService ]
    };
  }
}
```

I have more than 20 modules in my app and I use the shared module all over the place.  This works just fine.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use **BroswerModule** in  featureModule. So make sure you use **CommonModule** instead of using **BrowswerModule**.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ,SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ //.. here I have added all the components that generic uses ],
  exports:      [ CommonModule]
})
export class GenericModule { }
```

Comment: still getting the error : `nexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'GenericModule'`

Comment: i think one of the thing which you are importing was not found. check by removing one by one so that you will get which import gives you error

Comment: should I add GenericComponent to declarations inside generic.module too? @ranakrunal9

Comment: But you purpose is not clear. is it a lazy module or what? I can't see any connection bet GenericModule and AppModule. Why have you injected sharedModule everywhere? there are so many questions to ask.

Comment: I tried importing generic.component inside generic.module too, still not working

Comment: @micronyks I need to use generic.component inside generic.module & app.module., If I am importing generic.component in app.module then  it works for one iteration.but inside generic.component I am dynamically creating components which are declared inside generic.module. for eg. <generic-component component-name="jumbotron-component"></generic-component>. where jumbotron-component is included in generic.module

Comment: you have to declare all your component in `generic.module` declaration which you want to use inside your `generic.module`

Comment: @ranakrunal9 I have included generic.component inside declarations of generic.module too :(

Comment: @ranakrunal9 no ,`Type GenericComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModule and AppModule! Please consider moving GenericComponent to a higher module that imports SharedModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes GenericComponent then import that NgModule in SharedModule and AppModule`

Comment: If you want to use genericcmp in genericmodule and appmodule, why are you playing with sharedModule? There is a separate way to do it.